# Removing Comment Line breaks my code

Tags: php, forms, debugging, function

This function fails -

```
function check_required_fields($required_array) {
    $field_errors = array(); 
    foreach($required_array as $fieldname) {
        if ($fieldname == "date_expires_input") {
                if ($fieldname == "Expiration Date (Y/M/D)" || $fieldname == "N/A" ) 
//print "here";
                    {
                    $field_errors[] = $fieldname;
                    }
                } if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && !is_numeric($_POST[$fieldname])))
                {
                $field_errors[] = $fieldname;
                }
            }
            return $field_errors; 
        }
```

*BUT* when I uncomment  print "here", it works! (Although "here" is not printed). What the heck is going on?!

Comment: Fails how? Works how? One thing that catches the eye though: If you print "here", your `if` condition above will have no effect, and `$fieldname` will always be pushed to the array. THat is the most likely point of failure

Comment: Can you PLEASE change your title to something more problem-specific?

Comment: your braking style is a bit confusing....

Comment: if ($fieldname == "date_expires_input") then the next test if ($fieldname == "Expiration Date (Y/M/D)" || $fieldname == "N/A" ) can never be met, $fieldname can't have both "date_expires_input" AND ( "Expiration Date (Y/M/D)" || $fieldname == "N/A" ) as its value

Comment: Please choose an appropriate title. "What the heck is happening?" does not help at all.

Comment: @MarkBaker Oh, wow. I can't believe I didn't see that. What a dumb mistake. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks to whoever changed the title :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner condition is never met:

```
if ($fieldname == "Expiration Date (Y/M/D)" || $fieldname == "N/A" ) ...
```

can never be fullfilled as long as you are already sorting out one closure before with

```
if ($fieldname == "date_expires_input") ...
```

Comment: This one too, good eye. if `$fieldname == "date_expires_input"` it can never == `"Expiration Date (Y/M/D)"` too.

Comment: Yes, good eye! However, when I change it to $_POST[$fieldname] == Expiration Date...  it still fails

Comment: `Expiration Date (Y/M/D)` sounds like a very unusual name for a $_POST field. Are you sure, it's correct? What do you get when you do a `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: It's called that so the user knows what to enter in the field; it fades when the user clicks on it. When I do var_dump($_POST) I get this: string(24) " Expiration Date (Y/M/D)"

Comment: In addition, when I type in "N/A" into the expiration date, I *do* get the error message.. strange!

Comment: It was just an extra space before "Expiration Date" in the form -_-

Answer (score 4):

If you do

```
if ($fieldname == "Expiration Date (Y/M/D)" || $fieldname == "N/A" ) 
   print "here";
```

the following block isn't dependent of the if.

So uncommenting the `print "here";` is in practice simply removing the `if` for the following block of code.

Be careful to the indentation and the coherence of your braces, it helps avoiding this kind of bugs.

Comment: your conclusion is wrong... `if(foo) print "here";` is valid code

Comment: Of course it's valid. But the block after the `print "here";` is executed whatever the `if`.

Comment: He means that it is removing the `if` from the logic, not the code

Comment: no, the if is still there but the true case is just print "here" the follwoing block is just a grouped code outside this if.

Answer (score 2):

It fails because `print "here";` is not inside the braces for the `if` statement. This causes PHP to consider this single statement as the body of the `if` statement.

The following brace-delimited block is then executed unconditionally. Basically, it becomes equivalent to the following code

```
function check_required_fields($required_array) {
    $field_errors = array(); 
    foreach($required_array as $fieldname) {
        if ($fieldname == "date_expires_input") {
                if ($fieldname == "Expiration Date (Y/M/D)" || $fieldname == "N/A" )
                {
                    // Inside the if statement
                    print "here";
                }
                // Outside the if statement
                $field_errors[] = $fieldname;
                } if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && !is_numeric($_POST[$fieldname])))
                {
                $field_errors[] = $fieldname;
                }
            }
            return $field_errors; 
        }
```